# how many ways we can choose 3 and more consecutive number from set of N numbers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Counting subsets containing three consecutive elements (previously Summation over large values of nCr)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191702/counting-subsets-containing-three-consecutive-elements-previously-summation-ove)

Suppose we have a set like (1,2,3) then there is only one way to choose 3 consecutive number...its (1,2,3)....for a sets of 4 (1,2,3,4) we have 3 ways ( (1,2,3), (2,3,4), (1,2,3,4)) for five its 8 ,for 6 its 20, for 7 its 47 and so on....So for a given N, I can get the answer by applying brute force, and calculating all such subset having 3 or more consecutive number. Here I am just trying to find out a pattern, a technique to get the number of all such subset for a given N. The problem is further generalized to .....discover m consecutive number within a set of size N.

Comment: Are you sure it's $20$ for $n=5$? I think it should be $6$.

Comment: $ \frac{1}{2} \left(N^2-3 N+2\right)$

Comment: Do all of the numbers in the subset have to be consecutive, or does the subset just have to contain at least three consecutive numbers? In other words, is $\{1,2,3,5\}$ acceptable? If all of them have to be consecutive, see the hints below; if not, see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/191709/12042). In either case the number for $5$ is not $20$; it’s either $6$ or $8$.

Comment: srry for confusion its 8 for 5 and so on(typo mistkae), I have updated the question

Comment: for 5 the 8's are as...(3,4,5), (2,3,4), (1,2,3,4), (1,3,4,5), (1,2,3), (1,2,3,5), (1,2,3,4), (1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: @Marc Ah, I see. That is not how I had interpreted the question. When I read "choose 3 and ore consecutive numbers," I interpret this as the number of ways of choosing 3 consecutive, or 4 consecutive, or 5, etc. But in the example he posted, I see this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

The number of selections of $k$ consecutive things out of $n$ things in a row is given by $n-k+1$.